# Securing Istio ingress-gateway with TLS

Tags: istio

my goal is to secure my current spring boot application with TLS termination on an istio ingress-gateway.
So far my whole setup works with HTTP.

But when I try to set up the certificate for a specific domain the response to my request is 'connection reset by peer'.

My setup is running in a GKE cluster where I installed the istio demo configuration.

Here is my current setting:

**my-test-app deployment**

```
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: test-deployment
  labels:
    app: my-test-app
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app:  my-test-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-test-app
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: my-test-app-container
          image: ######
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - containerPort: 9080
          env:
            - name: SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE
              value: "k8s"
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: registry.###.com
```

**my-test-app service**

```
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-test-app-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: my-test-app
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      name: http
      port: 9080
```

**ingress-gateway settings**

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: my-gateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway 
  servers:
    - port:
        number: 80
        name: http
        protocol: HTTP
      hosts:
        - "*"
    - port:
        number: 443
        name: https
        protocol: HTTPS
      tls:
        mode: SIMPLE
        credentialName: my-credential 
      hosts:
      - "sub.example.com"
```

**virtual service**

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: my-virtual-router
spec:
  hosts:
    - "*"
  gateways:
    - my-gateway
  http:
    - match:
        - uri:
            prefix: /api/v1/sub1/sub2
      route:
        - destination:
            host: my-test-app-service
            port:
              number: 9080
```

When I do a curl under these settings, I get following:

```
* Preparing request to https://#########/api/v1/sub1/sub2
* Current time is 2020-12-#####
* Using libcurl/7.69.1 OpenSSL/1.1.1g zlib/1.2.11 brotli/1.0.7 libidn2/2.1.1 libssh2/1.9.0 nghttp2/1.41.0
* Using default HTTP version
* Disable timeout
* Enable automatic URL encoding
* Enable SSL validation
* Enable cookie sending with jar of 0 cookies
* Too old connection (665 seconds), disconnect it
* Connection 24 seems to be dead!
* Closing connection 24
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS alert, close notify (256):
*   Trying ###.###.###.###:443...
* Connected to ###.###.###.### (###.###.###.###) port 443 (#26)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
*   CApath: none
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* OpenSSL SSL_connect: Connection reset by peer in connection to ###.###.###.###:443 
* Closing connection 23
```

I am using a Let's encrypt cert which was received on another machine, due to the fact DNS update takes one day. For the import, I used the cert.pem and key.pem to create a secret in the cluster.

```
kubectl create -n istio-system secret tls my-credential --key=sub.example.com-key.pem --cert=sub.example.com-crt.pem
```

The scenario was only working when I changed the ingress-gateway setting for hosts `sub.example.com` to `*` and disabled certificate checking.

I'm hopefully looking forward to someone who can help me!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which istio version are you using?

Comment: Hi @Thomas I'm using the latest istio version istio-1.8.1 and cluster version 1.17.13-gke.2600

Comment: Please enable trace logging level in ingress gateway using. 
`kubectl -n $NS exec -it $POD_ID -- curl -X POST http://localhost:15000/logging\?level\=trace`
It will produce lot of output so save it to file using
`kubectl -n $NS logs $POD_ID > log.txt`

Comment: @SameerNaik thank you for your advise!
Can you give me a more detailed example what I should be looking for?
I was querying some data and created the log.

Does this information help in some way?
`debug envoy filter tls inspector: new connection accepted
trace envoy filter tls inspector: recv: 0
trace envoy filter tls inspector: recv: 517
trace envoy filter tls:onALPN(), ALPN: h2,http/1.1
trace envoy filter tls inspector: done: true`

Answer (score 0):

When you get `curl: (35) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer` when trying to connect to a seemingly correctly set up Istio Ingress Gateway, check the Kubernetes RBAC access permissions of the `istio-ingressgateway` Kubernetes service account that the ingress gateway is running with. This service account must have get, list, watch permissions on the Kubernetes Secret, containing the TLS credentials.

Typically, after Istio Ingress Gateway installation, the `istio-ingressgateway` Kubernetes service account gets appropriate RBAC access permissions to the Kubernetes Secrets in the same namespace into which it is getting installed, but not to any other Kubernetes namespace in the cluster.

If you create the the `Gateway` resource and TLS secret with TLS credentials referenced in it in some other namespace then the Istio Ingress Gateway pods won't be able to read the TLS certificate and serve the TLS endpoint. Then curl shows the `curl: (35) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer` error and there is pretty much nothing in the ingress gateway pods logs (including after turning on trace logging).

A sample RBAC check:

```
kubectl -n SECRET_NAMESPACE auth can-i get secret --as=system:serviceaccount:GATEWAY_NAMESPACE:istio-ingressgateway
```